# What does the 'charge' of the electron transform into when the electron gets converted to wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, charge, wave-particle-duality

Mathematically when a particle exhibits wave nature, its mass is supposed to be converted into energy. I want to know what happens to the charge of particle? what does the 'charge' of a non interacting material particle say an electron transforms into when it exhibits the wave nature?

Comment: What's the basis of your first sentence? Do you have a source for it?

Answer (score 6):

> Mathematically when a particle exhibits wave nature, its mass is supposed to be converted into energy.

Who said it? How did you get at this point?

> I want to know what happens to the charge of particle?

Really? Waves transport charges? This is vehemently wrong.

---

You really couldn't understand *Wave-particle duality*. It never, **in any way** does assert that the mass of the electron gets converted to energy, let alone its associated negative charge.

The wave you are talking about is ***purely of mathematical construct***; it assigns probability of finding electron at a certain coordinate at a certain time.

That's it.

Electrons are not classical particles; neither they are waves.

And please note that: **Electrons do not transit from *particle* phase to *wave* phase**. Electrons *are* electrons; they at times exhibit the **property** of particles and sometimes as waves.

**Waves are *probability waves***; not that electron's mass get converted to energy and all that.